# Does the sentence "How do you like Painting Exhibition?" make any sense?

Tags: grammaticality

Does this question make any sense? Is it grammatically correct?

> How do you like Painting Exhibition?

Answer (score 2):

"How do you like **the** painting exhibition" makes sense and is grammatically correct.  English uses articles before noun clauses like "painting exhibition".

The word "the" is the definite article.  Compare this to a word like "a" or "an" (indefinite article).  Example of the indefinite article: "How would you like to go to **a** painting exhibition?"

More about articles: http://www.ccp.rpi.edu/resources/article-usage/

More about how hard it is for non-native speakers of English to learn how to use articles and how some teachers are improving understanding of them: http://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/EJ903889.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I pressume it was the first part of the question (*How do you like*) what puzzled you, as it is a strange construction to English learners.

That construction might be a subject of some debate since the word "How" asks about the quality (good, bad, acceptable...) of something or the way (nicely, acceptably...) something is done. And yet, the real question here is about a quantity (i.e., "*How much* do you like it?"). That may be confusing for non-native speakers, but this construction is pretty common in everyday speech, and perfectly grammatical. Actually, it is also pretty common to hear "I like X *better* than Y", meaning you like it *more*. So once again, quality and quantity seem to mix together, for some reason unkown to me.

The only aspect that is not grammatical about your sentence is the absence of a determiner. The P in Painting shouldn't be capitalized, and it should be preceded by a determiner, preferably a "the".

So, to answer your question, it surely makes sense and is grammatically correct, if stated as follows:

> How do you like the painting exhibition?